# Where to change the developer information on Android built using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-api

Can anyone help me on where is the developer information stored (the censored gmail)? I want to update this to a different account but can't seem to find it in flutter project.

You can see from the below screenshot, an account was prompted, but that is not the account I want to show.

So where can I update this information?

[image: Screenshot]

I tried searching for the account email through out the whole project. Also tried updating the google-service.json with right account. But still showing a different account.

Comment: If you have the correct google-service.json in place, maybe it is not updated, try to uninstall the application.

Comment: have even tried deleting the project in firebase, then recreating it and then download new json. still showing wrong account.